# Flatten the target density in the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, importance-sampling

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ be a measure space
- $F$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space
- $f\in\mathcal L^1(\mu;F)$
- $f^\ast:E\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable with $$b:=\int f^\ast\:{\rm d}\mu\in(0,\infty)$$
- $p:E\to[0,\infty)$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable with $$\int p\:{\rm d}\mu=1$$

Assume we want to approximate $$I:=\int f\:{\rm d}\mu$$ using the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with target density $b^{-1}f^\ast$ with respect to $\mu$.

> Now, suppose $p$ is roughly proportional to $f^\ast$. Instead of $b^{-1}f^\ast$, we could use $$q:=b^{-1}\frac{f^\ast}p$$ as the target density. The idea is that $q$ might be significantly flatter and hence easier to explore by the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm than $b^{-1}f^\ast$.
>
> **Question**: Is there a name for such a scheme? And if so, is there any good reading where it is studied?

Comment: Are you familiar with importance sampling?

Comment: What is the connection between $f$ and $f^\star$?

Comment: @πr8 Yes, I am.

Comment: @Xi'an If $f^\ast$ is large, then $\left\|f\right\|_F$ is large.

Comment: What you're basically asking, as far as I can tell, whether or not it's a good idea to have a proposal density with heavier tails than the target density.  See for example slide 11 (and subsequent) from these lecture notes: http://www.jarad.me/courses/stat544/slides/Ch11/Ch11a.pdf.

Comment: If $p$ is a density, $q:=b^{-1}\frac{f^\ast}p$ is not a density. Furthermore, if $p$ is roughly proportional to $f^\ast$, the ratio $\frac{f^\ast}p$ is not necessarily integrable.